# Highest resolution GPS data in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

For iPhone4+ devices gps resolution, how best can it be? 1 meter, 2 meter or? 
I suppose that WiFi, cellular data usage and power are available.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your desired accuracy, and that will yield at best an accuracy of no smaller than 10 meters. This means that the device is at the coordinate, or somewhere in the circle around that coordinate with a radius of 10 meters.
Time-resolution is at best about one update per second.

Be mindful of the fact that the higher you desired accuracy, the more battery-power you consume.